# Convert 2 HTML file which is output from SQL query into 1 main HTML output file in shell script

Tags: shell-script, shell, sql, oracle

In shell script, I used 2 different SQL query & output of these 2 files in HTML format like `(eg- ab.html, cd.html)`. Before DML operation 1 SQL query will run then after DML operation another query will run. Shell script as ->

```
#/bin/ksh

ab=$(SQLPLUS -s <username>/<password>@DB <<EOF
set heading ON
set trimspool OFF
SET MARKUP HTML ON
set feedback off
spool ab.html
select col_1, col_2, col_3 from <tab>;
spool off;
exit;
EOF)

echo "$ab" > ab.html

----- DML operation perform

cd=$(SQLPLUS -s <username>/<password>@DB <<EOF
set heading ON
set trimspool OFF
SET MARKUP HTML ON
set feedback off
spool cd.html
select col_4 from <tab>;
spool off;
exit;
EOF)

echo "$cd" > cd.html

cat ab.html cd.html > output.html
exit 0
```

Then getting `output.html` file as ->

```
 ______________________________
| col_1     | col_2  |   col_3 |
| .....     | ...... |   ..... |
| .....     | ...... |   ..... |
|___________|________|_________|
 ______________________________              
|             col_4            |
|             ......           |
|______________________________|
```

But I want final `output.html` like col_1, col_2, col_3, col_4 column in one table like below ->

```
 ______________________________________
| col_1     | col_2  |   col_3  | col_4|
| .....     | ...... |   .....  | .....|
| .....     | ...... |   .....  | .....|
|___________|________|__________|______|
```

Could you please help me how to merge these 2 HTML file into one output HTML file so that we can able to see like above format.
I just draw HTML table as example but internal border always comes in HTML table, so please don't look HTML table format that I used.

Comment: Is this the same DB? Is it the same `<tab>`? Why don't you just merge the queries? `select col1, col2, col3, col4 from <tab>`

Comment: If you want help writing a script to parse some HTML, you have to show us that HTML rather than an image of the table that that HTML would display in a browser.